# What is the word for the words which are not spoken, but should be understood?

Tags: word-request

I want to know the word which means any word which is not spoken/written explicitly but should be understood.

Example: Person A has misbehaved with his parents. So somebody close to person A, say his wife, said "Don't you have any education of decency *that you should not misbehave with your parents,* left in you?"

The italicized parts are not said explicitly because it is clear from the context and is unnecessary to mention.

Comment: A closely related concept, which is not what you asked for in the question, is _common sense_.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Implicit*

Any communication contains *explicit* and *implicit* parts, the ones said/written and ones meant, but not passed literally.

In the example the speaker *implies* the subject should not misbehave with their parents.

This is pretty general but then it conveys the essence - *to imply* something is exactly the activity of conveying something without saying it, but the noun - *Implication* has broader meaning, so that won't quite do as the name of the activity.

There is also *Innuendo* but that's an entirely different way of conveying hidden meaning - the speech is about seemingly entirely unrelated subject and only by following the flow of metaphors you reach the hidden meaning - not what happens here.

And of course in the end there's the plain *meaning*. The speaker *meant* to stop the subject from misbehaving by parents. It doesn't exactly follow the "implicit" line - if you say "could you pass the salt please" you mean you want to have the salt passed to you, no hidden motives.

Comment: But implicit is a very general word and can be used anywhere. Isn't there any word related to in case of _implicit_ conversation only?

Comment: @Mistu4u: "Implied" and "implicit" ARE commonly used terms in the way SF said. See [this article](http://www.streetdirectory.com/etoday/implicit-andexplicit-communication-ucwjff.html), e.g., for more about implicit and explicit aspects of communication, and [this forum question](http://community.write.com/topic/25-if-a-sentence-has-an-implied-subject-is-it-still-a-fragment/) for more on _implied_ subjects. Perhaps this answer might have been better had it been beefed up with a few such references, but it's still a very good answer, even if those words can be used in other contexts.

Answer (score 2):

I'm in the U.S. When I was in school, we learned about "Understood Subjects" like the unspoken "You" in commands like "Come here". In ELU (another stackexchange site) I have seen "elided" used to mean words that are left out because they are understood. I also agree that "implied" is a good word for this, as suggested by SF.

Understood

Elided (This is where we get our word "ellipsis", the three dots, "...")

Implied

Answer (score 0):

Tacit: def. understood without being openly expressed.
I was reading Emma by Jane Austen when I read a word I didn't know, tacit, and I looked it up. Check dictionary.com if you want to, but that is where I got this definition of tacit. Implied is also a good fit, but I believe tacit is a notch closer.